# MySQL accepts incorrect data for date type

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE datetime_datatype1 (
    datedata DATE,
    timedata TIME,
    datetimedata DATETIME,
    timestampdata TIMESTAMP,
    yeardata YEAR
);

INSERT INTO datetime_datatype1
VALUES
    (
        '0010-8-22',
        '22:00:00',
        '10-11-28 22:02:00',
        '1970-12-30 11:00:40',
        '2155'
    );
```

datedata column is accepting date value `'0010-8-22'` without any error.

Actual `MySQL` date range is `1000-01-01 to 9999-12-31`

Answer (score 1):

From the [same link](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=2106) posted by [Shiv_k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6742912/shiv-k) (and erroneously marked as a bug in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39077373/2055152)):

> (...) this is not a bug.
>
> (...)
>
> The manual is correct as written.
>
> It says, "The *supported* range is...".  While you *may* be able to
>   use dates earlier than the supported lower limit, there is no
>   guarantee.

Answer (score -1):

Docs say: "The supported range for Date is '1000-01-01' to..."
but actual value is: 0001-01-01

This is Bug in MySQL refer the below link.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=2106

Comment: This is not a bug. Carefully read the link you posted, see my answer.